# Superbadge - Lightning Experience - Process Builder Challenge Issue

Tags: lightning, process-builder, trailhead, superbadges

I am currently attempting at challenge #6 in Lightning Experience Specialist.

This is what is given in the trailhead.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/super_badges/superbadge_lex

Fulfillment Cancellation Automation

> "Create a third process named Fulfillment Cancellation Automation to
>   handle cleaning up data if an opportunity is cancelled. If the
>   fulfillment is cancelled before the scheduled adventure date, the
>   explorer loses only their deposit. In this case, find the original
>   adventure package that triggered the creation of the fulfillment
>   record and update the sales price to equal only the deposit amount."

Data Model
[image]

This is the error which keeps on stomping for quite some time :(

The error message is also not that quite illustrative as to where the issue is.

[image]

As far as I know I have met all the requirements but for reasons unknown to me I am still getting that error.

**Process Builder Overview**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone tell me what I have been doing wrong ?

Comment: I did this with a flow, didn't anyone else do it with a flow?
Just passed in the deposit amount and adventurePackageId string and updated the adv package. I wouldn't actually build this like this, since we already have something setting the fulfillment records to cancelled, I would handle it all at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the error is in reading the requirement. You're changing the value of ALL Adventure Packages, not just the one related with the Fulfillment. You probably need to use the Product as a filter.

Answer (score 4):

Change the filter criteria of field update to below one:
[image]

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: bless you!!! I've been stuck on this step for a WEEK